# What is GND on board?

Tags: pins

I've looked in several places, and so far can not understand to want to be the GND who is on the board.

There is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the 0V reference for everything else, as well as the power supply return.

["Ground (electricity)" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_%28electricity%29)